# esc pos set page size ESC W cmd

Tags: thermal-printer

I read a lot of documentation about ESC POS printer and still don't understand how set page size cmd (ESC W) is working. It seems to be like high and low byte to define the x-y positions

this should be the explaination, I just want to understand how I set some x,y position by it

xL-xH - low and high byte of initial horizontal offset

yL-yH - low and high byte of initial vertical offset

dxL-dxH - low and high byte width of the page

dyL-dyH - low and high byte height of the page

[image]

Answer (score 2):

simply put:

- xL, yL, dxL, dyL are the remainder after division of x, y, dx and respectively dy to 256;
- xH, yH, dxH, dyH arre the integer part after division of x, y, dx and respectively dy to 256;

  ```
  public void setPageRegion(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      outputStream.write(new byte[] { 27, 87, 
          (byte)(x & 255), (byte)(x >> 8 & 255), 
          (byte)(y & 255), (byte)(y >> 8 & 255), 
          (byte)(width & 255), (byte)(width >> 8 & 255), 
          (byte)(height & 255), (byte)(height >> 8 & 255) };
  }
  ```

invoking `setPageRegion(0, 230, 830, 500)` will result in `new byte[] { 27, 87, 0, 0, 230, 0, 62, 3, 244, 1}`

Comment: Do you know how to set the vertical motion unit inside the page region ?